# How do I alter the precision of output from csv-writing in Racket?

Tags: csv, racket

I am using *display-table* from the *csv-writing* package, and would like to alter the default  precision when converting numbers to strings for output. I can see the docs say to use *make-csv-printing-params* and *#:number-cell->string*, but it also says it uses the ~r parameter *#:precision*. I tried to make all this fit together, but not successfully:

```
(display-table each_rank_table vars_out_port
           #:printing-params
           (make-csv-printing-params
           #:number-cell->string
           (~r #:precision 8)))
```

I assume I somehow need to get the cell value into ~r (?), so I presume I'm not going about this in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give it a function that takes a numeric argument and returns a string - one that just calls `~r` would be easiest.

Examples:

```lisp
(make-csv-printing-params
  #:number-cell->string (curry ~r #:precision 8))
```

or

```lisp
(make-csv-printing-params
  #:number-cell->string (lambda (n) (~r n #:precision 8)))
```

---

Note that if you want trailing 0's in the output, you need to use `'(= 8)` for the precision:

```lisp
> (~r 3.2 #:precision 8)
"3.2"
> (~r 3.2 #:precision '(= 8))
"3.20000000"
```

Comment: (If using `#lang racket/base`, you have to require `racket/function` to import `curry` and `racket/format` for `~r`).

Comment: Blatant self-promotion: You could also install my [`slib-format` package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/slib-format/index.html) to get a Common Lisp compatible `format` and use `(lambda (n) (format #f "~,8F" n))`

Comment: Thanks, Shawn - looks like I wasn't as far off as I thought. I do think the docs could be a little more explanitary at times, especially for us newbs - but the answer is often straightforward once it is explained.